# Greatest percentage of breakaway goals scored: location of goal

Tags: statistics, ice-hockey, nhl

For all goals scored in the NHL of the one-on-none variety (whether in-game breakaways or shootout goals), what location of the goalie getting beaten is the highest occurence?

I would think top shelf either side would be the lowest, 5-hole would be the highest, and lower-sides would be somewhere in the middle.

Comment: I would not say that the five hole is a place where a lot of goals get scored... Goalies always expect it.